# Указание параметров поиска в адресной строке

Tags: php

Может, кто-то знает, возможно ли передать параметры поиска в search.php из адресной строки?
Нужно передать человеку ссылку с результатами поиска, но не могу, т.к. после поиска в строке остаётся site.com/search.php. А хотелось, чтобы что-то такое было: `site.com/search.php?пропеллеры_и_диски`

Вот код search.php:

```
 <?php
require ('./includes/config.inc.php');
require (MYSQL);
// Validate the product type...
    $page_title = 'Результаты поиска';

// Include the header file:
include ('./includes/header.html');
include ('./includes/menu.html');

//if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
if ( isset ( $_POST['search'] ) )  {
    $search = $_POST['search'];
} else {
    $search = '';
}
$r = mysqli_query($dbc, "SELECT *, p.id AS product_id, `p`.`name` AS `product_name`, c.url AS cat_url, s.url AS subcat_url FROM products AS p, cats AS c, subcats AS s WHERE  p.catid = c.id AND p.subcat_id = s.id AND (article LIKE '%" .$search. "%' OR p.name LIKE '%" .$search. "%' OR description LIKE '%" .$search. "%')");
// For debugging purposes:
if (!$r) echo mysqli_error($dbc);

    include ('./views/search.html');

include ('./includes/footer.html');
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно заменить

```
if ( isset ( $_POST['search'] ) )  {
    $search = $_POST['search'];
```

на

```
if ( isset ( $_GET['search'] ) )  {
    $search = $_GET['search'];
```

и в html файлах в теге `form`, относящемуся к поисковой строке, удалить  `method="post"`

Answer (score 1):

Тогда придется использовать метод GET.

Одновременно с POST можно слать GET. Для этого в action формы вписывается URI с необходимыми параметрами, например, `action="http://example.com/some/path/another/one/?id=456"`.
В скрипте процессинга останется поддержать этот параметр, то есть проверять, есть ли `$_GET['id']`, и если есть, сделать что-то полезное.

Answer (score 0):

У тебя вот тут:

```
include ('./views/search.html');
```

формочка, и на ней актив стоит на `_POST` данные, нужно перевести на `_GET` и будет там отображаться.